# Delphi 10.4 Android Intent BroadcastReceiver and zebra scanner

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have a zebra barcode scanner. My app is developed using FMX Delphi. Can anyone help
me to configure zebra datawedge intent to receive the barcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try to implement solution based on intents (you have to reconfigure datawedge)

https://techdocs.zebra.com/datawedge/6-6/guide/api/tutorials/

Comment: Thank you very much.The problem solved with configuring datawedge. Can you suggest how to parameterized the server IP from android client using ini files.

Comment: sorry I have not idea how to configure ip server. I just used intents with datawedge and it worked ok for me

Answer (score 0):

I made one program. It works fine.
These codes are; Written for the Zebra MC2200 handled comp. DataWedge (BroadCastReceiver). [Rad studio 10.4 sidney]
note:I got help from a few examples here. Thank them. But none of them were fully viable for my purpose.

Class code sample

```delphi
unit BarkodOkur;

interface
uses
  Androidapi.JNIBridge, Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes, Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText, Androidapi.JNI.Embarcadero;

Type
  TBarcodeReceiver = class;

  TBarcodeReceiverListener = class(TJavaLocal, JFMXBroadcastReceiverListener)
  private
    FBarcodeReceiver: TBarcodeReceiver;
  public
    { JFMXBroadcastReceiverListener }
    procedure onReceive(context: JContext; intent: JIntent); cdecl;
  public
    constructor Create(const ABarcodeReceiver: TBarcodeReceiver);
  end;

  TIntentEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; const Intent: JIntent) of object;

  TBarcodeReceiver = class(TObject)
  private
    FBroadcastReceiver: JFMXBroadcastReceiver;
    FIntentFilter: JIntentFilter;
    FReceiverListener: TBarcodeReceiverListener;
    FOnIntent: TIntentEvent;
  protected
    procedure Receive(context: JContext; intent: JIntent); virtual;
    property IntentFilter: JIntentFilter read FIntentFilter;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property OnIntent: TIntentEvent read FOnIntent write FOnIntent;
  end;
implementation

uses
  Androidapi.Helpers;


{ TBarcodeReceiverListener }

constructor TBarcodeReceiverListener.Create(
  const ABarcodeReceiver: TBarcodeReceiver);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FBarcodeReceiver:= ABarcodeReceiver;
end;

procedure TBarcodeReceiverListener.onReceive(context: JContext;
  intent: JIntent);
begin
  FBarcodeReceiver.Receive(context,intent);
end;

{ TBarcodeReceiver }

constructor TBarcodeReceiver.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FReceiverListener := TBarcodeReceiverListener.Create(Self);
  FBroadcastReceiver := TJFMXBroadcastReceiver.JavaClass.init(FReceiverListener);
  FIntentFilter := TJIntentFilter.JavaClass.init;
  FIntentFilter.addCategory(TJIntent.JavaClass.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
//Here ('com.dwexample.ACTION') should be the "DataWedgw Action" record on the zebra handheld comp.
  FIntentFilter.addAction(StringToJString('com.dwexample.ACTION'));
  TAndroidHelper.Context.registerReceiver(FBroadcastReceiver, FIntentFilter)

end;

destructor TBarcodeReceiver.Destroy;
begin
  TAndroidHelper.Context.unregisterReceiver(FBroadcastReceiver);
end;

procedure TBarcodeReceiver.Receive(context: JContext; intent: JIntent);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnIntent) then
    FOnIntent(Self, intent);
end;

end.
```

application form

```delphi
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  BarkodOkur,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  Androidapi.JNIBridge, Androidapi.JNI.Embarcadero,Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  Androidapi.Helpers, Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Platform,  FMX.Platform.Android,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.Memo.Types, FMX.Memo, FMX.Edit, FMX.ScrollBox;

type

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Memo2: TMemo;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure ScannerReceiverIntentHandler1(Sender: TObject; const AIntent: JIntent);
    procedure ScannerReceiverIntentHandler2(Sender: TObject; const AIntent: JIntent);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  FScannerReceiver1 : TBarcodeReceiver;


implementation

{$R *.fmx}
{$R *.NmXhdpiPh.fmx ANDROID}




{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  AIntent: JIntent;
begin

  FScannerReceiver1 := TBarcodeReceiver.Create;
  FScannerReceiver1.OnIntent := ScannerReceiverIntentHandler1;

  AIntent:= TJIntent.JavaClass.init;
  AIntent.setAction(StringToJString('com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION_SOFTSCANTRIGGER'));
  AIntent.putExtra(StringToJString('com.symbol.datawedge.api.EXTRA_PARAMETER'), StringtoJString('START_SCANNING'));
  TAndroidHelper.Activity.sendBroadcast(AIntent);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  AIntent: JIntent;
begin

  FScannerReceiver1 := TBarcodeReceiver.Create;
  FScannerReceiver1.OnIntent := ScannerReceiverIntentHandler2;

  AIntent:= TJIntent.JavaClass.init;
  AIntent.setAction(StringToJString('com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION_SOFTSCANTRIGGER'));
  AIntent.putExtra(StringToJString('com.symbol.datawedge.api.EXTRA_PARAMETER'), StringtoJString('START_SCANNING'));
  TAndroidHelper.Activity.sendBroadcast(AIntent);
end;

procedure TForm1.ScannerReceiverIntentHandler1(Sender: TObject;
  const AIntent: JIntent);
var
  donen:string;
begin
//Here ('com.dwexample.ACTION') should be the "DataWedgw Action" record on the zebra handheld comp.
  if AIntent.getAction.Equals(StringToJString('com.dwexample.ACTION')) then
  begin
    donen:= JStringToString(AIntent.getStringExtra(StringToJString('com.symbol.datawedge.data_string')));
    Memo1.Lines.Add(donen);
  end;
  FScannerReceiver1.Destroy;
end;

procedure TForm1.ScannerReceiverIntentHandler2(Sender: TObject;
  const AIntent: JIntent);
var
  donen:string;
begin
//Here ('com.dwexample.ACTION') should be the "DataWedgw Action" record on the zebra handheld comp.
  if AIntent.getAction.Equals(StringToJString('com.dwexample.ACTION')) then
  begin
    donen:= JStringToString(AIntent.getStringExtra(StringToJString('com.symbol.datawedge.data_string')));
    Memo2.Lines.Add(donen);
  end;
  FScannerReceiver1.Destroy;
end;
end.
```

I used different receivers for different controls. I'm open to suggestions if there are other ways.